# Как проверить что пользователю доступен функционал?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

```
var testApp = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider){    
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/angular/templates/operation/Index.html',
        controller: 'OperationController'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/Operation/:operationId/Details', {    
        templateUrl: '/angular/templates/operation/Details.html',
        controller: 'OperationDetailsController'    
    });    
});
```

на сервере([asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) приложение) есть метод который возвращает `json` в случае если пользователь авторизован либо же `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized`

что бы *ограничить* доступ к *подробной информации* мне надо перед переходом на соответствующую страницу проверить наличие соответствующих привилегий

```
app.factory('accountService', ['$http',function($http){
    return {
        getCredentials: function(){
            let url = 'api/account/user';
            return $http.get(url);
        }
    }
}]);
```

я делаю это так:

```
$routeProvider.when('/Operation/:operationId/Details', {
    templateUrl: '/angular/templates/operation/Details.html',
    controller: 'OperationDetailsController',
    resolve: {
        isAuthenticated: function(accountService){
            accountService.getCredentials().then(function(){
                return true;
            }, function(){
                return false
            });
        }
    }
});
```

потом в контроллере я делаю так:

```
app.controller('OperationDetailsController', function($scope, $location, isAuthenticated){

    if(!isAuthenticated)
        $location.path('/Account/Login');
})
```

Но мне кажется что я делю что то не так/неправильно. Подскажите как *правильно* реализовать проверку доступности на стороне клиента.

P.S.: желательно с примером кода. заранее спасибо